# Erroneous count for feature list when there is one question with an active bounty

Tags: bug

[image]

"0 featured" 
1 question in the list

This is a bug, yes?

Comment: I do not see this behavior. The badge reads "1" for me. Perhaps a temporary glitch?

Comment: Like most "count" bugs I'll bet it's a caching issue;lots of them have come and gone. Haven't seen this one in particular before (and like above it seems fixed for me now, which also seems like caching)